# Angular + Jasmine - testing loaded BehaviorSubject as Observable in service

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an injectable service for getting a user's roles and permissions over HTTP. To ensure the HTTP call is made only once, I set up a BehaviorSubject inside the service and expose a public Observable, so any component injecting the service can subscribe to it to check whether permissions have loaded.

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  private _loaded = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public $loaded = this._loaded.asObservable();
  userDetailsUrl = "/serviceurl";

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.getUserDetails();
  }

  getUserDetails() {
    this._http.get(this.userDetailsUrl).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        // set permissions...
        this._loaded.next(true);
      }
    });
  }

  // getters for roles and permissions...
```

some.component.ts

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  loadedRoles: Subscription;

  constructor(private _user: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadedRoles = this._user.$loaded.subscribe({
      next: (data) => // get roles and permissions to restrict component functionality...
    });
  }
  // ...
```

In the specfile, I was expecting to be able to test the loaded subscription by calling getUserDetails again after service creation.

user.service.spec.ts

```
describe('SessionService', () => {
  let service: SessionService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  const userDetailsUrl = "/serviceurl";
  const data1 = {
    "roles": ["TESTER"]
  };
  let firstReq;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(SessionService);
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    
    firstReq = httpTestingController.expectOne({
      'url': userDetailsUrl,
      'method': 'get'
    });
  }));
  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should create and get user details over HTTP', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    expect(firstReq.request.method).toEqual('GET');
  });

  it('should be loaded', () => {
    service.$loaded.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log("post load", data);
        expect(data).toBeTruthy(); // since it passes true to the subscription
      },
      error: fail
    });
    service.getUserDetails();
    httpTestingController.expectOne({
      'url': userDetailsUrl,
      'method': 'get'
    }).flush(data1);
  });
  // ...
```

However, while it does update the $loaded Observable in the call, the 'should be loaded' test fails, apparently since the Observable initially has a false value, and I can see the log statement twice in the console output:

output

```
Browser application bundle generation complete.
LOG: 'post load', false
Chrome 105.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.022 secs)
LOG: 'post load', true
Chrome 105.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.022 secs)
Chrome 105.0.0.0 (Windows 10) UserService should be loaded FAILED
        Error: Expected false to be truthy.
            at <Jasmine>
            at Object.next (src/app/services/user.service.spec.ts:50:22)
            at ConsumerObserver.next (node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:91:1)
            at SafeSubscriber._next (node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:60:1)
Chrome 105.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.032 secs)
Chrome 105.0.0.0 (Windows 10) UserService should be loaded FAILED
        Error: Expected false to be truthy.
            at <Jasmine>
            at Object.next (src/app/services/user.service.spec.ts:50:22)
            at ConsumerObserver.next (node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Subscriber.js:91:1)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flush()` needs to be called on your mock request before the subscription happens. The `next()` callback is executed with the initial value of your BehaviorSubject because the Mock response hasn't come back at the point of subscription.